# How to call a lambda function with a message (M1) before another message (M2), but the output to be "M2 M1"?

Tags: c++, function, lambda

My homework is to implement a function called `finally`, which takes a procedure with 0 arguments and executes it at the end of the current scope. I should demonstrate its usage by using a lambda expression. After I create the lambda expression, I should call it right before `cout << "Hi" << endl;`.

Here's what I came up with until now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

auto finally = []()
{
    std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
};

void test()
{
    finally();
    std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    test();
    std::cout << "End of Main" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
Bye
Hi
End of Main
```

However, the final output needs to be:

```
Hi
Bye
End of Main
```

How can I swap the two messages without moving `finally()` from its current place?

Comment: make finally an object and write a destructor?

Answer (score 0):

A common technique in c++ is [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). You create an object, that when destructed will perform some action. Usually it will do something when created as well as when destructed, but not neccesarily.

To name a common example from the standard library, `std::ofstream` will close the file it's associated with when it's destroyed. You can manually call `close`, but it's usually not needed since it will be called automatically when the file stream is destroyed.

You can employ the same technique for your `finally`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
class RAII {
    public:
    RAII(F f) : func(std::move(f)) {}
    ~RAII() { func(); }

    private:
    F func;
};

template <typename F>
auto finally(F f)
{
    return RAII<F>(std::move(f));
};

void test()
{
    auto raii_finally = finally([]{ std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl; });
    //RAII raii_finally([]{ std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl; }); <-- c++17
    std::cout << "Hi " << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    test();
    std::cout << "End of Main" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`raii_finally` gets destructed at the end of the function, and in the destructor the lambda we passed in is called.

The function is redundant in this case and you could call the constructor of `RAII` directly if you use `c++17`.

Comment: That was pretty helpful! Thank you very much! :)